# Strange CLANG_WARN_NULLABLE_TO_NONNULL_CONVERSION warning

Tags: ios, clang, compiler-warnings, objective-c-nullability

I have activated the new compiler warning `CLANG_WARN_NULLABLE_TO_NONNULL_CONVERSION`. I could resolve most of the warnings, but one stems from a macro, and I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.

The macro looks like this:

```
#define MYAssertionFail(...) [[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInFunction:[NSString stringWithCString:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] file:[NSString stringWithCString:__FILE__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] lineNumber:__LINE__ description:__VA_ARGS__]
```

I get the following error:

> Implicit conversion from nullable pointer 'NSString * _Nullable' to
>   non-nullable pointer type 'NSString * _Nonnull'

Any idea how to rewrite the macro?

I already tried `__PRAGMA_PUSH_NO_EXTRA_ARG_WARNINGS/__PRAGMA_POP_NO_EXTRA_ARG_WARNINGS` but it did not help.

Comment: The pragma that you used ignores specifically "extra warnings" which is one of the hundreds of warnings settings. You need a similar pragma, but for the specific warning you want to filter out.

Comment: Yes, but there is no documentation at all for the null warning compiler setting. I would be thankful for a hit in the right direction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First:**

```
- (void)handleFailureInFunction:(NSString *)functionName file:(NSString *)fileName lineNumber:(NSInteger)line description:(nullable NSString *)format,... NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(4,5);
```

is wrapped in `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` and `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END`

**This means the compiler resolves this function declaration as:**

```
- (void)handleFailureInFunction:(NSString * _Nonnull)functionName file:(NSString * _Nonnull)fileName lineNumber:(NSInteger)line description:(nullable NSString *)format,... NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(4,5);
```

**Second**

```
+ (nullable id)stringWithCString:(const char *)bytes NS_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_4, 2_0, 2_0);
```

This function returns a nullable id, translated this is a `NSString * _Nullable`

**To conclude**

It should be enough to add a cast in your function call like so:

```
#define MYAssertionFail(...) [[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInFunction:(NSString * _Nonnull)[NSString stringWithCString:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] file:(NSString * _Nonnull)[NSString stringWithCString:__FILE__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] lineNumber:__LINE__ description:__VA_ARGS__]
```

If you want to read up on nullability in Obj-C and Swift, please read this Apple blog post about this matter: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25